# Where can I find a current tail risk indicator?

Tags: risk, indicator, hedge

The definition of tail risk (risk of 3-standard deviations movement) seems to imply there would be a current market indicator for this.

Is there such an indicator available somewhere?

Comment: would Value-at-Risk or expected shortfall meet the needs. they are tail risk measures

Comment: Not sure what access you have, but State Street publishes a Tail Risk Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter feed of [Taleb](https://twitter.com/nntaleb) is a decent predictor.

Other than that, most of the stuff that you find is proprietary and somewhat subjective/vague. Here is a [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1386418115000403) that proposes VVIX index as a tail risk indicator:

> This paper reports that the volatility-of-volatility implied by VIX
> options has predictability for tail risk hedging returns.
> Specifically, an increase in the volatility-of-volatility as measured
> by the VVIX index raises current prices of tail risk hedging options,
> such as S&P 500 puts and VIX calls, and lowers their subsequent
> returns over the next three to four weeks. The results are robust to
> jump risk, skewness, kurtosis, option liquidity, variance risk
> premium, and limit of arbitrage. The predictability can be explained
> by either risk premiums for a time-varying crash risk factor or
> uncertainty premiums for a time-varying uncertain belief in
> volatility.

Answer (score 2):

St. Louis Fed Financial Stress Index - https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/STLFSI2

There are others (e.g. from the sellside) but this is publicly available.

EDIT: looks like some of the sellside indicators are published on Bloomberg (no permissioning required), e.g. GFSI Index from BAML.

Comment: Also the OFR FSI https://www.financialresearch.gov/financial-stress-index/

Answer (score 2):

Bollerslev and Todorov have a paper on this: *Tails, Fears, and Risk Premia*, Jrl of Finance, (December 2011), pages 2165-2211 ([link](https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/todorov/htm/papers/jrp.pdf)) . If you have option data, you can simply apply their method. Very often, academics publish their codes and their data on their website -- maybe either of them, or someone else who quote them have the codes.

Comment: Hi @Stéphane : Could you give a link to a paper? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/fmishkin/papers/nberwp.w16150.pdf

> We consider seven well-established FCIs: the Bloomberg FCI, the Citi FCI, the
> Deutsche Bank (DB) FCI, the Goldman Sachs (GS) FCI, the Kansas City Federal Reserve
> Financial Stress Index (KCFSI), the Macroeconomic Advisers Monetary and Financial
> Conditions Index, and the OECD FCI.